# Cannot open text file Android

Tags: android, file

I am getting an error saying that the file I am trying to open does not exist.

Below is the code I am using to do the read and write

```
private void writeToFile(String file,String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("saved.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());

    }
}

private String readFromFile(String file) {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(file);

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new   InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The error I am getting is File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication/files/checked.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: the filename is `saved.txt`

Comment: Agreed. Your `openFileOutput()` call refers to `saved.txt`. Your error refers to `checked.txt`.

Comment: oh boy i feel dumb.  Thanks guys =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

The error I am getting is File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication/files/**checked.txt**: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Must use **saved.txt**